# Any way to add an exportable property to an ABPerson

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, abaddressbook, vcf-vcard

The vCard 3.0 standard allows for extending the cards with custom field with a "X-" prefix. However adding a property via Objective-C's `addPropertiesAndTypes:` and `setValue:forProperty:` methods do not seem to result in an addition that will be exported to it's vCard format. Information added that way gets saved to the address book, but if you export the card to share with someone else, the new property gets left behind.

Is there a way using the AddressBook framework to add a vCard extension (like "X-") that will be exported and imported with the card?

If I edit an exported vCard manually, that added property is not displayed in Address Book, but is persistent through subsequent exports. It seems like there should be a way to programmatically write to an ABPerson that would result in a "X-" vCard property, and then subsequently read that custom property in.

Thanks for any/all help

Answer (score 0):

If it's not doing this out of the box, perhaps you could write the code yourself, and maybe swizzle it into the ABPerson class using Objective-C [method swizzling](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MethodSwizzling). Unfortunately, any functionality you add that way will only be used if *your app* is the one doing the exporting and importing. Since you're talking about vCard which is effectively an interchange format, that's probably less than completely helpful. (Not to mention that method swizzling is a total hack.)

Some quick experimentation in the debugger convinces me that the C interface just calls the Objective-C methods behind the scenes, so I'm guessing there'll be no additional functionality available there either.

Interestingly, you said...

> If I edit an exported vCard manually, that added property is not
>   displayed in Address Book, but is persistent through subsequent
>   exports.

...but I did not see this behavior. Re-exports of an imported, hand-edited vCard don't contain my X-FOOBAR field. This makes the situation look even worse -- this means, for instance, that if someone imported a vCard containing your extension fields with the Address Book app, you'd likely lose those fields.  But maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Perhaps you could piggyback on the NOTE field?